# What is the purpose of "use curl --cookie with a file that doesn't exist"?

Tags: curl, http, cookie

From https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

> Curl's "cookie engine" gets enabled when you use the --cookie option.
>   **If you only want curl to understand received cookies**, use --cookie
>   with a file that doesn't exist. Example, if you want to let curl
>   understand cookies from a page and follow a location (and thus
>   possibly send back cookies it received), you can invoke it like:
>
> ```
> curl --cookie nada --location http://www.example.com
> ```

What is the purpose of "use --cookie with a file that doesn't exist"?

What does "if you only want curl to understand received cookies" mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using the `-L` option ("follow through 3XX redirects") and also using `--cookie` with a non-existing file, `curl` will sent in subsequent requests the cookies set in previous responses without storing them permanently anywhere. IMHO, instead of using a non-existing file, using `--cookie /dev/null` would be safer and will achieve the same effect.

Curl will **not** send back any cookies by default, unless the `--cookie` or `--cookie-jar` options were used. But many sites will send you into infinite redirects if you don't accept their cookies; however, you may not want to store any state on disk and let them track you through separate `curl` invocations.

Example with a bogus `--cookie` file:

```
curl --cookie nada -v -L https://www.google.com/news -o /dev/null 2>&1 | egrep -i 'cookie|Connected to|^> GET|^< HTTP'

* Connected to www.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:803::2004) port 443 (#0)
> GET /news HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/2 302
* Added cookie NID="158=LONG-GARBAGE" for domain google.com, path /, expire 1564698265
< set-cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01-Aug-2019 22:24:25 GMT;HttpOnly
* Connected to news.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e) port 443 (#1)
> GET /news HTTP/1.1
> Cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE
< HTTP/2 301
* Connected to news.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e) port 443 (#2)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE
< HTTP/2 302
* Connected to news.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e) port 443 (#3)
> GET /?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en HTTP/1.1
> Cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE
< HTTP/2 200
```

And without one:

```
curl -v -L https://www.google.com/news -o /dev/null 2>&1 | egrep -i 'cookie|Connected to|^> GET|^< HTTP'

* Connected to www.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:803::2004) port 443 (#0)
> GET /news HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/2 302
< set-cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01-Aug-2019 22:24:43 GMT;HttpOnly
* Connected to news.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e) port 443 (#1)
> GET /news HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/2 301
< set-cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01-Aug-2019 22:24:43 GMT;HttpOnly
* Connected to news.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e) port 443 (#2)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/2 302
< set-cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01-Aug-2019 22:24:43 GMT;HttpOnly
* Connected to news.google.com (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e) port 443 (#3)
> GET /?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/2 200
< set-cookie: NID=158=LONG-GARBAGE;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01-Aug-2019 22:24:43 GMT;HttpOnly
```

Notice how the second invocation ignores the cookies set in responses with `set-cookie` instead of sending them back in requests.

Comment: Thanks. Is --cookie without a real file only used when you're using the -L option ("follow through 3XX redirects")?

Comment: " if you don't accept their cookies". how can you make curl not accept cookies?

Comment: 1. `-L` is a case where `curl` does multiple requests in a single invocation; other case is where you're using `curl` with multiple urls. 2. by not using any `--cookie` option as I did in the 2nd example. "Accepting cookies" means sending them back in requests, in a  `Cookie: ` header.

Comment: If by "record" you mean copying the string somewhere so it could be sent back with subsequent requests, then, yes, you'll have to "record" it. The server doesn't know or care what you doing with it, as long as you're sending it back, so it could keep state and track you through multiple requests. This is already quite offtopic, but there's another method you could keep state in HTTP -- by encoding it in the url. The downside of that vs. cookies is that it's too obvious to the user ;-)

Comment: I second the question of how to make curl not accept cookies at all. Wget has the "--no-cookies" flag. Is there an equivalent in curl? Unless perhaps not accepting cookies is the default in curl.

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott haven't I answered that [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497741/what-is-the-purpose-of-use-curl-cookie-with-a-file-that-doesnt-exist/497803?noredirect=1#comment916069_497803)? "__by not using any `--cookie` option__, as I did in the second example". Not accepting cookies is the default AFAIK. Am I missing something?

Comment: It wasn't clear. I was just seeking a clarification. That's all I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott I've tried to clarify the answer a bit, and include the suggestion to use `/dev/null` instead of non-existing file, which may turn up to exist when you suspect it the less ;-)